# Finding icon location

Tags: icons, customization

Can Anyone tell me the exact location of these icons. I have installed flat icons but these still look the same. Also can I change these with a custom icon of mine?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Suggestion: Consider to add more information to your question: What is the name of flat icons that you had installed? How did you install the flat icons?

Comment: Alternatively, run this command `ls /usr/share/icons` on your system and post the output in your question. That is the least information I need before posting any answer.

Comment: @clearkimura Just like Canonical, I have ditched Unity.

Comment: The way I see, this question has nothing to do with Unity itself. More like whether the icon theme that is installed has those dedicated icons or not. So the answer much depends on what icon theme in use.

Comment: Am I not being clear here? this question was asked on 3 Apr and you gave a reply on Dec 17. By this time, Ubuntu started shipping with Gnome. So I don't use Unity anymore in simple terms. So I cant follow any of your instructions right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find icon files in `/usr/share/icons`.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But I want to find the exact .filename of this icon so that I can change it.

Comment: @Alan Jameson, if you want to find, search.

Comment: @M.Becerra search with what name? Please be elaborate.

Comment: If you dont bother searching, why do you expect others to do so?

Comment: -1 because OP probably knew icons were installed there (otherwise how OP manage to install the flat icons by own?). Also, OP is asking for exact location, not generic ones.